# Lua long strings not displaying correctly using geshi syntax highlighting

Tags: php, lua, geshi

I am storing my new Lua code in to a Dokuwiki system which uses the geshi highlighter (written in php).  How ever I am having a problem with long string definitions in lua  for example

```
strLong = [[If this is a long string then I don't want it 
highlighted as code else it looks very silly]]
```

It is possible to correct this using the geshi lua.php file,  I have already taken a quick look at the documentation at http://qbnz.com/highlighter/geshi-doc.html and multiline comments are working fine it's just multiline strings which are not.

Comment: I normally go change Lua code fragments from being Markdown code (indent four spaces) to being <pre> tagged because of the wacky highlighting that Lua gets. But for this question, it makes sense to leave the strange highlight intact as emphasis. ;-)

Comment: Thanks,  my problem is not so much the output here, which I suspect is using a similar highlighter, but my Knowledge base, as it uses geshi to display the code.  I suspect I might need to take a dig in the geshi code for an answer, or avoid using multi-line strings.

Comment: I've upvoted both Q and A for your efforts.... I don't believe that SO is using geshi for code highlighting, but regardless of whose highlighter it is, it doesn't handle Lua sources nicely at all. I did fuss a primitive Lua mode into the weird and ancient emacs clone (epsilon from www.luguru.com) I use on Windows mostly so it would get indentation closer to right. I certainly heartily endorse fixing the highlighter rather than avoiding `[[...]]` strings.

Comment: @RBerteig  -  Thanks for the votes,  I will take a look at epsilon on www.lugaru.com and see what I make of it.  I normally use PsPad for editing on windows.  I'll remember to use the pre tip here if I need to post any code.

Comment: I started using epsilon on DOS before Windows 3.0 was shipping, and have kept paying them for upgrades ever since. I have to admire a company that is that stubbornly still in business. And they hired Duane Bibby to illustrate their manual after seeing his work on the TeX Book, even though you could easily argue that an editor manual didn't *need* artwork....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Thanks to Benny Baumann on the geshi-users list

> Strings in GeSHi 1.0.X have the limitation that start and end marker
>   need to be the same. If this constraint is not fulfilled you have to
>   resort to highlighting the strings using COMMENT_REGEXP.

To correctly colour code the long strings 
In lua.php
In the $language_data = array (
add

```
    'COMMENT_REGEXP' => array(2 => '/\[\[(?s:.*?)\]\]/'),
```

In the style sheet add

```
.lua  .co2  { color: #ff0000; font-style: normal;}
```

to change only second comment type to look like a string, when used on a Lua source.